# jQuery - Enable/Disable a button following checkboxes state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 to develop a web app. I have a page which contains a submit button which should be enabled only if one of my two checkboxes (or both of them) is (are) enabled. The thing is, I'm trying to add an "or" operator in the following script but it does not give me what I want. So, here's my script :

[The jQuery sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bluz/peans/)

And this is the part I'd like to improve :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    the_terms = $("#the-terms");
    the_terms2 = $("#the-terms2");

    the_terms.click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

And I can't find a way to tell my document "Okay, if one of these 2 checkboxes (or both of them) is (are) checked, we can press on the button. If not, don't allow it".

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LhVN5/)**

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', !$('.checkbox:checked').length > 0)
});
```

Note:

- This find the checkboxes by class name `checkbox` so it will work with two checkboxes, whereas your original code is looking at a single checkbox via its ID.
- Use the `change` event not `click`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
$(".checkbox").click(function() {        
    $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", !$('.checkbox:checked').length);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/peans/153/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   the_terms = $("#the-terms");
   the_terms2 = $("#the-terms2");

   $('.checkbox').change(function(){
       $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", !(the_terms.is(":checked") || the_terms2.is(":checked")));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make a function to be called on onload or on click
function checkTerm() {
    jQuery('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',!jQuery('input.term:checked').length > 0 ) ;
}

// Call the function on load
$(document).ready(checkTerm) ;

// And call it on check change
jQuery(document).on('change','input.term',checkTerm) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below modified script , please check if it works as you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
the_terms = $("#the-terms");
the_terms2 = $("#the-terms2");

 if(the_terms.is(":checked") || the_terms2.is(":checked"))
 {
   $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
 }
else
{
    $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

the_terms.click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") || the_terms2.is(":checked")){
        $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});

 the_terms2.click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") || the_terms.is(":checked") ){
        $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});

});
```